# Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found when i use kubernetes client python in pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to get kubernetes api server from a pod.

Here is my pod configuration

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: test
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: test
            image: test:v5
            env:
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: ['python3']
            args: ['test.py']
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

And here is my kubernetes-client python code inside test.py

```
from kubernetes import client, config

# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
    print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

But i am getting this error:

```
kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When operating in-cluster you want `load_incluster_config()` instead.

Comment: Thank you 
 The error is disappeared  but i see this know
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (403)
Reason: Forbidden
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden:

Comment: You will need to set up a ServiceAccount and RBAC permissions for it using the various Role/Binding types, just like you would grant permissions to a human.

Comment: How can i do that ?. Do you have any example ?

Comment: See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/ for a starting point.

Comment: i mean, does i need to do changes inside my python code ?

Comment: No, the access control is entirely external from your code. You are correctly making an API request but that request is being rejected.

Comment: you can see an example if the 403 exception occurs under the following link (its shown in the comments): https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/in_cluster_config.py